# Custom viewgroup with animated view

Tags: android, animation, viewgroup

I made a custom viewgroup, and I need to use view animation to rotate some views...

But they are misbehaving, no matter if I put the startanimation inside onDraw, onLayout or onMeasure, my views flicker (you see them briefly rotated, and then briefly non-rotated, and that pattern repeats).

How I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [Android transfer animation of view in custom viewgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683032/android-transfer-animation-of-view-in-custom-viewgroup) and [Animating Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views)

```
view.animate().rotation(180);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your animations work properly in a non-custom viewgroup?

I tried to use a custom ViewGroup in order to create an animated background, however, just like you, I had some strange behaviour. I solved it by simply using a FrameLayout and inserted two fill_parent views: a custom one and a LinearLayout. Then the LinearLayout which came on top of my custom view was working as expected.

Comment: It works properly in non-custom viewgroup. But I need it to work inside the viewgroup.

Comment: I don't know if that is possible because the custom onDraw interferes with drawing of your View widgets children.